# How to use Lamar 2 with ASP.NET Core 3 preview?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, lamar

I configured Lamar with ASP.NET Core 3 but I got an error

```cs
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection' to type 'Lamar.ServiceRegistry'.'
```

My config in `Program` class:

```cs
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseLamar();
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

and `Startup` class:

```cs
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        //public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        //{
        //    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        //    {
        //        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        //        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        //        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        //    });
        //    services.AddMvc()
        //        .AddNewtonsoftJson();
        //}

        public void ConfigureContainer(ServiceRegistry services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            // Supports ASP.Net Core DI abstractions
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();            
            services.AddLogging();

            // Also exposes Lamar specific registrations
            // and functionality
            services.Scan(s =>
            {
                s.TheCallingAssembly();
                s.WithDefaultConventions();
            });
        }
```

Based on the documentation I replaced `ConfigureServices` with `ConfigureContainer` but I got the error that I mentioned above.

[image]

Can anyone help me to use Lamar with ASP.NET Core 3 preview?

**UPDATED**
As #Tom Style wrote, the accepted answer is quite old and depreciated, so he put the new one see his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try replacing HostBuilder with the old one like this:

```
 public static IWebHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseLamar()
            .UseUrls($"http://*:80")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a long term solution as `IWebHostBuilder` is now deprecated. But I'm struggling to find an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

IWebHostBuilder will definitely work but is now deprecated.

This code sample shows how to use it with the modern IHostBuilder interface.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
   Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseLamar();
      .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
      {
          webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
      })
```

[Official docs link](https://github.com/JasperFx/lamar/blob/master/src/LamarWithAspNetCoreMvc3/Program.cs)